# Wordpress search by tag

Tags: wordpress, url, search, plugins, tags

Does "Wordpress" include "search by tag in URL" plugin ? Soo  I want to have the possibility to search in my URL for a specific word and my page to give me all posts ,comments related to that word or where that word is used in my page. How can I do that ?

I tried a search plugin but it gives me the possibility to search only in admin site , and not from the URL